# Opening a File in onedrive from two different computers

Tags: c#, file, filestream, onedrive

I have an app that acceses files in one drive.I can easily create/read the file from the computer that i developed the app. As soon as I test the app in another computer I get this error **The file cannot be accessed by the system**. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The interesting part is I can see the file is there by calling on ***File.Exists(fPath)*** but I still cannot open it.
I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `FileStream` is only for local files... Not clear how that relates to working with files on OneDrive.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I login into onedrive before i use FileStream. As I mentioned I have no problem at all if I use my app on the computer I developed the app in. I the problem in another pc/laptop,

Comment: Read permission issue ? try to open the file with explorer.

Comment: @Graffito I tried no problem there at all :)

Comment: Is your app winforms, WPF or Asp.net? ASP.NET may do some "impersonation". The identity will be then be anonymous user or the authenticated request user.

Comment: @Graffito I just tried to create a new file in the hosting machine (another laptop than the one i was developing in) and the app could easily open it. It looks like it has something to do with the permission.

Comment: @Graffito it is a Winforms app. Is there any way to indicate that the file stream shoulkd create the file in a way it is accessible by another machine?

Comment: May you clarify who(what app, what computer) creates the file and who(what app, what computer) reads it ?

Comment: @Graffito it is a smple app that first logs into one drive and simply stores a *.ini file in a folde. For example Im sitting on my PC and create a note and save it on the *.ini file. Then i turn on my lap top, and i use the same app that will first look into the predefined folder in OneDrive. If the file exists it tried to read it. Here i get the problem that on the laptop i cant open the file. Simply put: If I create any type of file on a compuer in OneDrive, I can't open it via filestream in another computer that is logged in with the same credentials into one drive

Comment: When the exception is raised, was the .exe loaded from network? In that case, you must check that the app is fulltrust.

Comment: @Graffito the app is installed on both machines. But How can i make it Full trust anyhow?

Comment: To give fulltrust to an assembly, use [caspol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx)

Comment: @Graffito Thanks a lot. This is not working either. And also since I have the app installed on both computers I can skip this full trust. I'll do some more research. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Graffito I tried to recreate the file by copying it and then replace it with the old one. I can easily delete the file buy I cannot copy it. Here is the code:<br/>
`FileIOPermission ioPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read,   
ioPerm.Demand();
 try
            {
            File.Copy(filePath, @"C:\Users\arvind\OneDrive\tmp.ini", true);
                File.Delete(filePath);
                File.Move(@"C:\Users\arvind\OneDrive\tmp.ini", filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string s = e.Data.ToString();
            }
        }`

Comment: I am not a file/network security specialist, so  I can't really help. For more info, read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5724/Understanding-NET-Code-Access-Security).

Comment: @Graffito I understand. Thanks for the help so far anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it. The only thing i have to do is right click on the folder/files in OneDrive and choose "Make available offline"